# How to verify JSON string and return error if JSON is not okay

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl, express

I am trying to verify if a JSON object is okay or not. I have this server that should be able to return me true if the JSON is okay or an error if isn't. 
I'm using curl to make the request like this:

curl -D- -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"user","pass":"uwish"}' 'http://localhost:8020/register'

At the server script the console log calls verifyJSON and returns false, but the JSON object is fine.

I would like to catch the error while parsing (if JSON is not correct) and send it to the client. I tried to accomplished that but I'm not really sure about what I did.
 If someone could help me I would be very appreciated. Thank you for your time.
Here is the server code:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var corsOpts = { origin: '*' };
var app = connect();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors(corsOpts)).use(function (req, res, next) { 
console.log(req.method);
console.log(req.url);
if(req.url === '/register' && req.method === 'POST')
    register(req,res);
else
    if(req.url === '/ranking' && req.method === 'GET')
        ranking(req, res);

}).listen(8020);

console.log("Server running on 8020");

function register(req , res){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var somedata = {}; // return this object if JSON req is okay

console.log(req.body);
console.log(verifyJSON(req.body));

//trying to send the error to the client

if( err = verifyJSON(req.body) ){
    somedata.error = err; // not sure if this is right
    res.end(JSON.stringify(somedata));
}
else
    console.log("do something with this JSON data");

}

function verifyJSON(str){
try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
return true;    
}
```

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, in production, you shouldn't send JSON to a server **just** to determine if it is validly formatted...

Comment: That's not the purpose of it. I just want to make sure that the JSON data I'm receiving is valid to go further with it. @LukePark

Comment: @snobis `JSON.parse`: if it parses, it is valid JSON (although it could be filled with completely bogus data). If it does not parse (and throws an exception), it is invalid. Since this is what `verifyJSON` does, I am not sure what the question is .. generally the data would be used, making the 'verify' redundant as it throws away the parsed data.

Comment: @snobis In the 'not valid' case there is no `res.end`, which could be .. problematic. If the `verifyJSON` call returns false then it's not valid JSON - so what *is* the value read from `req.body`?

Comment: You can try use JSON.parse(json_string) with try/catch to validate your json string. If get err in catch then it is not valid else is valid json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a try...catch around parse to check the validity of the json input, returning the actual error message instead of just true or false.

```
function verifyJson(input){
   try {
      JSON.parse(input);
   } catch(ex) {
      return ex.message; // Is invalid 
   }
   return false; // Is valid 
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it returns the error {"error":"Unexpected token o"}. Not sure why. The JSON is valid

Comment: That sounds correct... It returns an error with the message.